# Проверка каждого слова в тексте JS на наличие URL

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, url

Я новичок в JS и мне нужно: есть переменная text содержащая текст с N количество слов, нужно проверить текст и выделить все домены в нём и заменить их на ссылки. Например www.mydomain.ru - это домен. mydomain.ru - тоже домен. нужно найти все домены в тексте вне зависимости от количества доменов 2 и более уровня. Например домен vk.com система должна заменить на `<a href="https://vk.com">vk.com</a>` если в тексте содержится домен типа http://pokemon.go то нужно произвести тоже самое но http:// или https:// вырезать. То есть имеется текст в неём

https://go.pro заменится на`<a href="https://go.pro">go.pro</a>`

http://samsung.com заменится на `<a href="https://samsung.com">samsung.com</a>`

oracle.com заменится на `<a href="https://oracle.com">oracle.com</a>`

mysql.myadmin.jino.ru заменится на `<a href="https://mysql.myadmin.jino.ru">mysql.myadmin.jino.ru</a>`

Так же слешы должны быть сохранены то есть

https://go.pro/hero/8 заменится на `<a href="https://go.pro/hero/8">go.pro/hero/8</a>`

http://samsung.com/galaxy/S10+ заменится на `<a href="https://samsung.com/galaxy/S10+">samsung.com/galaxy/S10+</a>`

oracle.com/java заменится на `<a href="https://oracle.com/java">oracle.com/java</a>`

mysql.myadmin.jino.ru/page/new/thebest/pc заменится на `<a href="https://mysql.myadmin.jino.ru/page/new/thebest/pc">mysql.myadmin.jino.ru/page/new/thebest/pc</a>`

https://mysql.myadmin.jino.ru/page/new/thebest/pc заменится на `<a href="https://mysql.myadmin.jino.ru/page/new/thebest/pc">mysql.myadmin.jino.ru/page/new/thebest/pc</a>`

В уме пока что у меня не может сложиться как подобное можно реализовать, помогите пожалуйста, возможно есть готовые функции и скрипты

**Примечание: домен это минимум 2 буквы до и после последней точки!**
Если у домена есть поддомен 2ого 3его и более уровней то каждый их них не менее 2х символов.

Comment: Ваша поэма нам не о чем не говорит, что уже пробовали вы, где код, где попытки?

Comment: С радостью можно рассказать о попытках когда они хотя бы что-то могут упростить для ответа. Но как я это сделаю если я понятия не имею как можно перебрать текст по пробелам и каждое между 2я пробелами проверить на нужное. Я PHP программист, JS честно не знаю, по этому и пытаюсь сюда писать ибо в интернете ничего годного за пол часа не нашёл. Если есть приблизительное то всё равно не то.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Нужно найти URL в тексте.
- Поиском подстрок в тексте занимаются регулярные выражения.
- Нужно создать (найти) регулярное выражения для обнаружения URL.
- Создавать долго, воспользуемся поиском по запросу "url regex detect"
- Находим показательный пример (https://www.regextester.com/96504) регулярного выражения ищущего URL в тексте.
- Нужно применить найденное выражения в коде на JS для поиска и замены на ссылки.
- Нужно узнать, как искать и заменять на JS.
- Опять ищем в поиске "js regex replace".
- Находим ответ: variable.replace(/regex/, "new string");
- Причём в "new string" должна помещаться вся найденная строка, находим в выданных нам страницах, каким образом она обознается.
- Поиск говорит, что `$&` содержит всю найденную строку, подходящую для заданного регулярного выражения.
- Теперь можно составить необходимый нам код на JS, используя полученные выше знания.

```js
var textWithURLs =
'http://foo.com '+
'http://goo.gl '+ 
'https://foo.com '+
'https://www.foo.com '+
'https://www.foo.com/ '+
'https://www.foo.com/bar '+
'http://foo.com/. http://foo.com/! http://foo.com/, '+
'www.cool.com.au '+
'http://www.cool.com.au '+
'http://www.cool.com.au/ersdfs '+
'http://www.cool.com.au/ersdfs?dfd=dfgd@s=1 '+
'http://www.cool.com:81/index.html';

var textWithLinks = textWithURLs.replace(/(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|\b(?:[a-z\d]+\.))(?:(?:[^\s()<>]+|\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\([^\s()<>]+\)))?\))+(?:\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\(?:[^\s()<>]+\)))?\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))?/ig, '<a href="$&">$&</a>');

alert(textWithLinks);
```

Пример выражения и проверяемых ссылок взят отсюда https://www.regextester.com/96504

Comment: Очень много лишнего в выражении. Некоторые группы просто никчемны.

Comment: @And предложите лучше, нажмите править, я не против, если работать будет.